# SQL Server Compact fast insert of data information? c#

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I am using SQL Server Compact Edition.

I have a FOR loop for build my queries to insert data so I download as 3000 rows from a full-blown SQL Server.

I need to insert these 3000 rows into SQL Server Compact Edition, and currently I do an insert for every row which takes a lot of time. I need to do this for 12 tables, and that would take a very long time... I need a faster method to do this in less than 5 minutes...

Do you know any way for to get a insert a lot of rows on SQL Server Compact?

I tried do insert of fifty on fifty but I got an ERROR...

```
insert into table(col1,col2) 
values (val1,valo2) ; 
insert into table(col1,col2) 
values (val1,valo2)
```

I got error with 2 insert (so its not going to be able for to do 50 inserts),

Is it possible to do `OPENROWSET` in SQL Server Compact Edition?

MY QUESTION
How can I insert a lot of rows into a SQL Server Compact Edition database? 
I get this data from a full-blown SQL Server database.

Comment: Can you consider editing so it's not all train of thought?

Comment: @simchona MY QUESTION how can i insert a lot of rows on sql compact? (i need it was FAST) information i connected it with sql server (no compact)

Comment: SQL CE can easily insert 50 records quickly and without errors. Please tell us what error you are getting so we can understand what is going on.

Comment: Last I checked, SQL CE does not allow compound statements in one command.  By having one command with multiple statements separated by a ";", you're breaking that.

Comment: @dour i separated querys with ";" and when the another insert sentence start THERE i have the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> do you know any way for to get a insert a lot of rows on sql compact?

See below for what I think is the best solution, but if you don't like it (for whatever reason) *and* your source database is SQL Server you could consider making a linked server in SQL Server to your compact database and letting SQL Server insert the records. From my experience, SQL Server inserts into arbitrary databases pretty quickly.

## [SQL Compact Bulk Insert Library](http://sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com/)

> .NET Library for loading data fast (doing bulk inserts) into a SQL Server Compact database file. Attempts to mimic the SQLClient SqlBulkCopy API.
>
> Some timings from testing - load 2 column table with no constraints/indexes:
>
> 1,000,000 rows: 6 seconds = 166,666 rows/second
> 5,000,000 rows: 28 seconds = 178,000 rows/second

```
private static void DoBulkCopy(bool keepNulls, IDataReader reader)
{
    SqlCeBulkCopyOptions options = new SqlCeBulkCopyOptions();
    if (keepNulls)
    {
        options = options |= SqlCeBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls;
    }
    using (SqlCeBulkCopy bc = new SqlCeBulkCopy(connectionString, options))
    {
        bc.DestinationTableName = "tblDoctor";
        bc.WriteToServer(reader);
    }
}
```

Comment: what does it mean??   options = options |= SqlCeBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls;

Comment: The project has it's own documentation, but by and large it mimics the `SqlBulkCopy` API. So you can check out the intended behaviour on MSDN: [Preserve null values in the destination table regardless of the settings for default values. When not specified, null values are replaced by default values where applicable.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopyoptions.aspx).

Comment: @angeluc `a |= b` is equivalent to `a = a | b`. See http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/07/22/c-fundamentals-combining-enum-values-with-bit-flags.aspx

Comment: thank you very much, i'll try it later it is so late now.. i see it very interesting

Comment: i have a error on bc.WriteToServer(datatable) (i am using datatable) this is the error : The operation completed successfully

Comment: Those are some impressive benchmarks, but I was able to insert 1000000 rows using plain old SQL statements in under a minute. If @angel is getting an error trying to insert 50 rows the problem is not SQL.

Answer (score 1):

It should take less than a second to insert 3000 rows into 12 tables using plain SQL statements. If you are getting errors, or it is taking minutes, you are doing something wrong. This is a very basic task, if you are getting errors you should find out what is going wrong, not try using different tools.

The simplest way to insert records into a SQL CE database using C# is to use ADO.NET. Here is an example using parameterized queries:

```
using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection(YourCommandString))
{
    var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table (col1,col2) VALUES (@val1,@val2)";

    var param1 = cmd.CreateParameter();
    param1.ParameterName = "@val1";
    // assign col1 types, constraints, lengths here.
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);

    var param2 = cmd.CreateParameter();
    param2.ParameterName = "@val2";
    // assign col2 types, constraints, lengths here.
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);

    cmd.Prepare();
    conn.Open();
    foreach (var s in sourceDataStructure)
    {
        param1.Value = s.sourceValue1;
        param2.Value = s.sourceValue2;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    cmd.Dispose();
}
```

if you do not know what a parameterized query is, you should learn.

Comment: This line: param1.ParameterName = "@val2"; should be param2.ParameterName = "@val2"; no?/stimmt?